# Is there a word that means to multiply by 1.5, or to increase by 50%?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that means “to multiply by 1.5,” or “to increase by 50%?”

I’m familiar with “double,” “triple,” etc. for the first few integers greater than 1. And I assume there isn’t a convention for constructing words for all possible rational multipliers. But 1.5 seems like a sufficiently common case that there might be a special word for it?

Comment: Is there a *single* word? Not that I'm aware of. There are several ways of describing it, but they involve more than just one word.

Comment: There's the single-word ***decimate***, which you could argue means ***to multiply by 0.9*** (or ***decrease by 10%***). But it only works with certain referents, such as *populations*.

Comment: Perhaps **three-halves** (the same style as *three-quarters*). When we had half penny coins, the sum was referred to as "three-halfpence" or typically "three-ha'pence".

Comment: "Increase by half" is probably the best-understood term for increasing by 50%.  Such terms tend to become ambiguous very easily.

Comment: "Half as much again" is a common idiom but not a single word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn’t exist, but you could try inventing something like

> sesquible

Some would quibble, but the prefix *sesqui* means one-and-a-half, and is used in compound names in chemistry.

Indeed, some have quibbled and suggested the more elegant:

> sesquify

or

> sesquate

I leave it to the classical scholars and genuine linguists to decide which is preferable.

Comment: I would maybe say "sesquate".

Comment: Or *sesquify*, perhaps.

Comment: Wow. Great words. I have a Ph.D. in chemistry and never heard *sesqui* before. Must have been the wrong kind of chemistry. Inorganic, I presume. I would go with *sesquify*. +1

Comment: @RichardKayser — I have a bachelors degree in chemistry from the ancient times, but remembered sesquihydrates (or perhaps encountered them later in reagent catalogues when I jumped ship and became a molecular biologist). Google autocomplete led me to sesquioxides, which seem to have more fans.

Comment: Cool. Good stuff. In retrospect, I have heard the term *sesquihydrates*.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I remember the "sesquicentennial" celebration when I was living in Texas in 1995. Thanks!